# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain null cert chain

Tags: java, ssl, exception

I have a Server and I have a client. I have both of them running on the same machine. am trying to establish an SSL connection between the client and the server. i have generated certificates for both the server and the client with the following keytool command.

For Client
keytool -keystore clientstore -genkey -alias client -validity 3650

Then i export the root certificate of the client to a cer file callled client.cer

For Server
keytool -keystore serverstore -genkey -alias server -validity 3650
Then i export the root certificate of the server to a cer file callled server.cer

I now import the client certificate "client.cer" into the serverstore keystore with the following command

keytool -import -keystore serverstore -file client.cer -alias client

And also import the servers certificate "server.cer" into the clientstore keystore with the following command

keytool -import -keystore clientstore -file server.cer -alias server

After doing this, i imported both the server.cer and client.cer into the cacerts Keystore. But when i try to establish an ssl connection, i get this error on the server **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain** and this error on the client javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate.

My Servers Code.

```
package serverapplicationssl;


import java.io.*;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.PrivilegedActionException;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import java.security.Security;

import java.io.*;

public class ServerApplicationSSL {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean debug = true;

    System.out.println("Waiting For Connection");

    int intSSLport = 4447;

    {
        Security.addProvider(new Provider());

    }
    if (debug) {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
    }
    FileWriter file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileWriter("C:\\SSLCERT\\Javalog.txt");

    } catch (Exception ee) {
        //message = ee.getMessage();

    }

    try {

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\SSLCERT\\OntechServerKS"), "server".toCharArray());
        file.write("Incoming Connection\r\n");

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
                .getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(keystore, "server".toCharArray());

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) context.getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketfactory.createServerSocket(intSSLport);
        sslServerSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslServerSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
        sslServerSocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);
        SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();
        //SSLServerSocket server_socket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocket;

        sslSocket.startHandshake();

     // Start the session
        System.out.println("Connection Accepted");
        file.write("Connection Accepted\r\n");

        while (true) {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sslSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

            String inputLine;

            //while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println("Hello Client....Welcome");
            System.out.println("Hello Client....Welcome");
            //}

            out.close();
            //in.close();
            sslSocket.close();
            sslServerSocket.close();
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception exp) {
        try {
            System.out.println(exp.getMessage() + "\r\n");
            exp.printStackTrace();
            file.write(exp.getMessage() + "\r\n");
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception eee) {
            //message = eee.getMessage();
        }

    }

}

}
```

Here's My Clients Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class SSLConnect {

public String MakeSSlCall(String meternum) {
    String message = "";
    FileWriter file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileWriter("C:\\SSLCERT\\ClientJavalog.txt");

    } catch (Exception ee) {
        message = ee.getMessage();

    }
    //writer = new BufferedWriter(file );
    try {
        file.write("KeyStore Generated\r\n");
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\SSLCERT\\SkyeClientKS"), "client".toCharArray());

        file.write("KeyStore Generated\r\n");
        Enumeration enumeration = keystore.aliases();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            String alias = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
            file.write("alias name: " + alias + "\r\n");
            keystore.getCertificate(alias);
            file.write(keystore.getCertificate(alias).toString() + "\r\n");
        }
        TrustManagerFactory tmf =TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(keystore);
        file.write("KeyStore Stored\r\n");
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
        context.init(null, trustManagers, null);

        SSLSocketFactory f = context.getSocketFactory();
        file.write("About to Connect to Ontech\r\n");
        SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("192.168.1.16", 4447);
        file.write("Connection Established to 196.14.30.33 Port: 8462\r\n");
        file.write("About to Start Handshake\r\n");
        c.startHandshake();
        file.write("Handshake Established\r\n");
        file.flush();
        file.close();
        return "Connection Established";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            file.write("An Error Occured\r\n");
            file.write(e.getMessage() + "\r\n");
            StackTraceElement[] arrmessage = e.getStackTrace();
            for (int i = 0; i < arrmessage.length; i++) {
                file.write(arrmessage[i] + "\r\n");
            }

            file.flush();
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception eee) {
            message = eee.getMessage();

        }
        return "Connection Failed";
    }
}
}
```

Stack Trace Execption on my Server

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1937)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:292)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientCertificate(ServerHandshaker.java:1804)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:222)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:957)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:892)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1050)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at serverapplicationssl.ServerApplicationSSL.main(ServerApplicationSSL.java:69)
```

Stack Trace Execption on my client

```
Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
SSLConnect.MakeSSlCall(SSLConnect.java:96)
BankCollectSSLCon.main(BankCollectSSLCon.java:13)
```

What could be causing this error?, could it be because i am running both the server and the client on the same machine?...Been on this for quite a while now. i need help

Comment: Did you find out what the issue was? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Posted The Answer

Answer (score 3):

@WiteCastle Yes I did, and trust me i had a real unpleasant experience finding out what the issue was. Before i paste my snippet of code, let me start by explaining the SSL Communication.SSL Connection between client and Server.

1. Client Says Hello
2. Server says Hello.
3. Server Presents. Certificate for Validation.
4. Client checks if certificate is in its TrustStore.
5. Server request for client certificate.
6. Client presents certificate for server to validate.
7. If the clients certificate passes validation communication can now
   occur.

So the javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain error happens when the client certificate failed validation on the server and javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate happens when server cannot find the certificate the client presented in its truststore.
So what i did was

For The Client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class SSLConnect {

public String MakeSSlCall(String meternum) {
String message = "";
FileWriter file = null;
try {
    file = new FileWriter("C:\\SSLCERT\\ClientJavalog.txt");

} catch (Exception ee) {
    message = ee.getMessage();

}
//writer = new BufferedWriter(file );
try {
    file.write("KeyStore Generated\r\n");
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    keystore.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\SSLCERT\\SkyeClientKS"), 
"client".toCharArray());

    file.write("KeyStore Generated\r\n");
    Enumeration enumeration = keystore.aliases();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        String alias = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
        file.write("alias name: " + alias + "\r\n");
        keystore.getCertificate(alias);
        file.write(keystore.getCertificate(alias).toString() + "\r\n");
    }
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
                .getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(keystore, KeystorePassword.toCharArray());
    TrustManagerFactory tmf =TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    tmf.init(keystore);
    file.write("KeyStore Stored\r\n");
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

    context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustManagers, null);

    SSLSocketFactory f = context.getSocketFactory();
    file.write("About to Connect to Ontech\r\n");
    SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("192.168.1.16", 4447);
    file.write("Connection Established to 196.14.30.33 Port: 8462\r\n");
    file.write("About to Start Handshake\r\n");
    c.startHandshake();
    file.write("Handshake Established\r\n");
    file.flush();
    file.close();
    return "Connection Established";

} catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        file.write("An Error Occured\r\n");
        file.write(e.getMessage() + "\r\n");
        StackTraceElement[] arrmessage = e.getStackTrace();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrmessage.length; i++) {
            file.write(arrmessage[i] + "\r\n");
        }

        file.flush();
        file.close();
    } catch (Exception eee) {
        message = eee.getMessage();

    }
    return "Connection Failed";
}
}
}
```

For Server

```
package serverapplicationssl;


import java.io.*;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.PrivilegedActionException;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import java.security.Security;

import java.io.*;

public class ServerApplicationSSL {

public static void main(String[] args) {
boolean debug = true;

System.out.println("Waiting For Connection");

int intSSLport = 4447;

{
    Security.addProvider(new Provider());

}
if (debug) {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
}
FileWriter file = null;
try {
    file = new FileWriter("C:\\SSLCERT\\Javalog.txt");

} catch (Exception ee) {
    //message = ee.getMessage();

}

try {

    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    keystore.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\SSLCERT\\OntechServerKS"), 
"server".toCharArray());
    file.write("Incoming Connection\r\n");

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
            .getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(keystore, "server".toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory tmf =TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    tmf.init(keystore);
    file.write("KeyStore Stored\r\n");
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustManagers, null);

    SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) context.getServerSocketFactory();
    SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketfactory.createServerSocket(intSSLport);
    sslServerSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslServerSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
    sslServerSocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);
    SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();
    //SSLServerSocket server_socket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocket;

    sslSocket.startHandshake();

 // Start the session
    System.out.println("Connection Accepted");
    file.write("Connection Accepted\r\n");

    while (true) {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sslSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        String inputLine;

        //while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println("Hello Client....Welcome");
        System.out.println("Hello Client....Welcome");
        //}

        out.close();
        //in.close();
        sslSocket.close();
        sslServerSocket.close();
        file.flush();
        file.close();
    }

} catch (Exception exp) {
    try {
        System.out.println(exp.getMessage() + "\r\n");
        exp.printStackTrace();
        file.write(exp.getMessage() + "\r\n");
        file.flush();
        file.close();
    } catch (Exception eee) {
        //message = eee.getMessage();
    }

    }

}

}
```